# Почему не срабатывает событие change?

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть такой код. На чекбокс установлен слушатель событий. При изменении чекбокса появляется/пропадает красный блок. Так же существует еще и кнопка, при нажатии на которую, ставиться галочка, т.е. чекбокс изменяется с помощью javascript'a, но слушатель событий не отлавливает это действие. Как можно исправить (т.е. при нажатии на кнопку по сути красный блок должен появиться).

```js
var fromToBlock = document.querySelector('.from-to');
fromToBlock.style.display = 'none';
var fromToCheckbox = document.querySelector('#input');
var fromToBtn = document.querySelector('button');


fromToBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 fromToCheckbox.checked = true;
});


fromToCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
 if(fromToCheckbox.checked) {
  fromToBlock.style.display = 'flex';
 } else {
  fromToBlock.style.display = 'none';
 }
});
```

```css
.from-to {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id='input'>
<label for="input">Click</label>



<div class="from-to">
  some block
</div>

<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fromToBlock = document.querySelector('.from-to');
fromToBlock.style.display = 'none';
var fromToCheckbox = document.querySelector('#input');
var fromToBtn = document.querySelector('button');


fromToBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 //fromToCheckbox.checked = true;
    fromToCheckbox.click();

});


fromToCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
 if(fromToCheckbox.checked) {
  fromToBlock.style.display = 'flex';
 } else {
  fromToBlock.style.display = 'none';
 }
});
```

```css
.from-to {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id='input'>
<label for="input">Click</label>



<div class="from-to">
  some block
</div>

<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Нет, Вы не поняли, нужно сделать именно так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку чекбокс становился активным. Т.е. если чекбокс неактивен, то ничего не происходит при нажатии на кнопку. А у вас клик на кнопку работает также как и при клике на рам чекбокс.

Comment: Слушатель события не отлавливает изменение свойства чекбокса,  т.е. "чекбокс изменяется с помощью javascript'a, но слушатель событий не отлавливает это действие". Это действительно так, чтобы слушатель события получил его надо его создать и распространить на узле. Но это можно упростить при имитироавнии клика создается событие автоматически.

Comment: Но нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку чекбокс стал checked = true и все. При повторном нажатии ничего не должно происходить, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Нужно делать так делай. Проверяй если checked = true плежде чем его менять.

Comment: на слушателе события `click` по кнопке проверяй, чекнут ли чекбокс, если да, то инициируй событие `click` по чекбоксу (как показано в ответе)

Answer (score -2):

Дело в том что событие `change` не работает с `checkbox`. Это решается таким образом:

```
fromToCheckbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
if(fromToCheckbox.checked) {
fromToBlock.style.display = 'flex';
} else {
fromToBlock.style.display = 'none';
}
});
```